# IOError(Stalefile) exception being thrown by Kafka Streams RocksDB

Tags: apache-kafka, openshift, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

When running my stateful Kafka streaming applications I'm coming across various different RocksDB Disk I/O Stalefile exceptions. The exception only occurs when I have at least one KTable implementation and it happens at various different times. I've tried countless times to reproduce it but haven't been able to.

**App/Environment details:**

- Runtime: **Java**
- Kafka library: **org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:2.5.1**
- Deployment: **OpenShift**
- Volume type: **NFS**
- RAM: **2000 - 8000 MiB**
- CPU: **200 Millicores to 2 Cores**
- Threads: **1**
- Partitions: **1 - many**

**Exceptions encountered:**

- Caused by: `org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.ProcessorStateException: Error while getting value for key from at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.get(RocksDbStore.java:301)`
- `Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.ProcessorStateException: Error restoring batch to store at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore$RocksDBBatchingRestoreCallback.restoreAll(RocksDbStore.java:636)`
- `Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.ProcessorStateException: Error while range compacting during restoring at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore$SingleColumnFamilyAccessor.toggleDbForBulkLoading(RocksDbStore.java:616)`
- `Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.ProcessorStateException: Error while executing flush from store at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.flush(RocksDbStore.java:616)`

Apologies for not being able to post the entire stack trace, but all of the above exceptions seem to reference the `org.rocksdb.RocksDBException: IOError(Stalefile)` exception.

**Additional info:**

- Using a persisted state directory
- Kafka topic settings are created with defaults
- Running a single instance on a single thread
- Exception is raised during gets and writes
- Exception is raised when consuming valid data
- Exception also occurs on internal repartition topics

I'd really appreciate any help and please let me know if I can provide any further information.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Posix file system, this error means that the file system returns ESTALE. See description to the code in https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html